# Set notation for conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, notation, conditional-probability

Consider [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf#Justification_of_idf) for the probability that a given document $d$ contains a term $t$ as the relative document frequency:

$$P(t|D)={\frac {|\{d\in D:t\in d\}|}{N}}$$

What does $:$ mean in the numerator here? (i.e. how do you read that expression?), is it "*and*"? If so, is that equivalent to e.g. a comma?

Comment: "such that" - the numerator is the size of the set of all documents $d \in D$ such that the term $t$ is in $d$.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132351/a-pedantic-question-about-notation-such-that-symbols

Answer (score 1):

In [set builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate) the colon is often read as "such that" or "where".  It is somewhat

So, as explained on the wiki page, $\lvert\{d\in D: t\in d\}\rvert$ is "the size of the set of documents ($d$) in the corpus ($D$) where the term ($t$) occurs in the document".

- The placeholder, $d$ is a local variable for any element of the set which we are constructing.
- the domain selection, $d\in D$, occurring before the colon (though it *may* be placed after), indicates we are constructing a set from the elements in $D$ . Here the corpus, $D$, is a collection of documents.
- the predicate, $t\in d$, occurring after the colon, indicates that we are filtering these elements that have the property of containing $t$.  Documents beings a collection of terms.

Likewise, $N$ is the size of the corpus: $N\,{=\lvert D\rvert\\=\lvert\{d\in D\}\rvert}$.

So $\mathsf P(t\mid D)$ is an abbreviation for $\mathsf P(\{d\in D:t\in d\}\mid D)$, and since the set is a subset of the corpus, $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(t\mid D)~&=~\dfrac{\lvert\{d\in D:t\in d\}\cap D \rvert}{\lvert D\rvert}\\&=~\dfrac{\lvert\{d\in D:t\in d\}\rvert}{N}\end{align}$$